# WebView show nothing when load some URL on Android

Tags: android, webview

I have a demo with WebView on Android. Here is my code:

```
public class AuthPortalActivity extends Activity {

    WebView authPortalWebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.auth_portal_activity);

        authPortalWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.auth_portal_webview);

        authPortalWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewPortal());
        openProvisioningPortal();
    }

    private void openProvisioningPortal() {
        authPortalWebview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        authPortalWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        authPortalWebview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        authPortalWebview.loadUrl("https://example.com");
    }

}

class WebViewPortal extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("TAG", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading url = " + url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.d("TAG", "onPageFinished");
    }
}
```

It can load some URL like Google, Facebook... But when I try with my Portal URL, it can not show anything. Sure my Portal using "https" and it also load successfully if I use browser like Chrome...

Here is my WebView after load URL and method **onPageFinished** had been called.

[image]

Did I forgot something in my code ??

Answer (score 1):

either return `false` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to proceed loading the url normally

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.d("TAG", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading url = " + url);
    return false;
    //     ^^^^^
}
```

or

You have your own client `WebViewPortal` so you need to load the url as well

```
  @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("TAG", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading url = " + url);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ load the url once you receive web view and link
        return true;
    }
```

WebViewClient is responsible to process the request and proceed according to the notifications onPageFinish or started etc.

Comment: I have tried with another device a few minutes ago, and I see it just happen with my Asus Z010D. If I try with another device, my code still run perfectly. So I think I should change something on my Asus device settings, maybe enable Javascript ? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: with your current implementation, it shouldn't work on any device though for Asus `Android System WebView is now handled by Google Chrome. If you want to enable Android System Webview, you need to disable Chrome.`  source : https://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone-3/help/android-n-major-issues-android-n-update-t3573926

Answer (score 0):

```
use this line in Androidmanifest.xml 
//-------------this is Internet permission-------------------


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">

    </uses-permission>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this line"? Your answer contains multiple lines.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">

    </uses-permission>

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain all relevant information instead of adding them to the comment section

Comment: Sure I add that permission to Androidmanifest.xml, and my code can run on all devices, except Asus